# adding and retrieving arrays from localStorage

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to retrieve value from localStorage but below code is printing `NULL` in browser Console instead of array object values! any one can help me with this please

```
var ary = [];

function setFavorite(n, v) {
    alert("a=" + n + " ,v=" + v);
    var obj = {};
    obj[n] = v;
    ary.push(obj);
    // Put the object into storage
    localStorage.setItem('testObject', JSON.stringify(ary));
    // Retrieve the object from storage
    var retrievedObject = localStorage.getItem('ary');
    console.log('retrievedObject: ', JSON.parse(retrievedObject));
}
setFavorite("Power", "Power Converter"); //calling above function from a button click
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are adding the object under the `testObject` key but you are fetching the value of the `ary` key, hence why nothing is returned.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pewn1d4m/1/) with a simple illustration for adding and retrieving arrays from `localStorage`

Comment: can you tell me , how can i retireve it back in for each loop so that i can print Name & value in console together

Comment: Do you mean that you want to retrieve the array stored in `localStorage` and then look over everything printing key and value?

Comment: How can i push only unique names which are not available in `ary`

Answer (score 1):

Hm, typo I guess: 'ary' hasn't been stored.

You stored "testObject".

```
var retrievedObject = localStorage.getItem('testObject');
```

should do the trick.